# Importing task from csv file into rally

Tags: jira, rally

I have the csv file of multiple task and I want to upload it in one user story in rally.
However, I am bit confused what would be the formatting required to do that. you just need Name and Work product to upload task (I checked on internet). I have attached the task which i want to upload and also attached the error screenshot as well.Is format of csv file is correct?

I am new to rally.

[Image I want to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1A3A.png)

[The Error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fxgq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is potentially caused by the quotation marks, i.e. *"Work Product"* is not a column name whereas *Work Product* is. For example, when I test a csv upload file in Notepad it shows like this:

```
Work Product,Name
US1,Test task name
```

The fields you're using should be fine, refer https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/agile-development-and-management/rally-platform-ca-agile-central/rally/reporting-top/importing-and-exporting-data.html